# can't set up swagger with jax-rs

Tags: swagger, jax-rs, cxf

I can't understand, why swagger doesn't work with my spring boot jax-rs app.

I add this dependencies to pom.xml:

```
                <!-- Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

also I set up -> cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=true in application properties,my rest requests:

```
@Path("/")
@Api("/")
@Service
public interface IService {

  @GET
  @Path("/health")
  @ApiOperation("/health")
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
  public Status getStatus();

  @GET
  @Path("/info")
  @ApiOperation("/info")
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
  public Info getInfo();

}
```

work as I expected, but I can't get documentation, when I call:

http://localhost:8000/swagger-ui.html

get -> Whitelabel Error Page.

Maybe someone can help me?

just in case here is my properties file:

```
#cxf url mapping
cxf.path=/api
cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=true
cxf.jaxrs.classes-scan-packages=com,org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.swagger.Swagger2Feature,org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs,org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.swagger.ui.SwaggerUiResourceLocator

#port
server.port=8000
server.servlet.context-path=/
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the complete project?

You'll find working samples in https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/cxf-3.3.4/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jax_rs, if you start a new project I suggest to go with OpenAPI v3 instead of Swagger.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to use this samples for my task.