# How to use swagger with a generic jaxrs api that writes response based on query params and response body is written using response builder class

Tags: java, swagger, jax-rs, swagger-ui, api-documentation

How to use swagger with a generic jaxrs api that writes response based on query params and response body is written using response builder class... Any example would be appreciated.

How to use swagger with a generic jaxrs api that writes response based on query params and response body is written using response builder class....

Comment: maybe the question [can't set up swagger with jax-rs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59414438/cant-set-up-swagger-with-jax-rs) could help. There are lot of examples on how to setup swagger in a project. if you have an error doing that, please provide [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.